# jquery change element to element

Tags: jquery, html

Контакты

```
if(window.location == 'http://my.site.com/contacts/')
{
    $('.menuwelcome').css('display', 'block');
    $('.leftlink').find('Контакты').css('font-weight', 'bold');
    $('#mcontacts').find('a').html('<b>Контакты</b>').remove();
}
```

How do remove tag "a" html, and change his for `'<b>Контакты</b>'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the first two lines of JavaScript here, but here's a way you could do what you ask for:

```
var link = $('#mcontacts a'),
  linkValue = link.html();

link.replaceWith('<b>' + linkValue + '</b>');
```

Answer (score 0):

.......

```
$('#mcontacts a.u').remove();
$('<b>Контакты</b>').appendTo($('#mcontacts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mcontacts a').wrapInner('<b />')
```